# how to make image map of footer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a navigation bar fixed to the bottom right of the page, which i've done, and I was about to go make an image map out of it, until i went into dreamweaver and my image wasnt even popping up to draw around, i was going to do it manually until i wondered, will this even work? (since it is in fact moving all the time, its hard to make coordinates on it.) how would I go about turning my image into workable clickable buttons?

[image: here's what my footer looks like]

Comment: It's moving?  Is this an animated gif on your site?  Dreamweaver is a good tool for setting up image maps.  You may need to check the path to your image in Dreamweaver so that it can find the image so you can see to draw the imagemap.  You can set up an imagemap manually, but I find it's a lot of trial, error and frustration.  A visual tool will save time and give you results you like.

Comment: its not an animated gif. it's moving in that, when you resize the browser it stays in the corner. and when you scroll it continues to stay in the corner. thats it! i'll double check my path. thanks :)

Comment: but would an imagemap still work on something that is fixed to the bottom right?

Comment: If you are using an img tag for this image, then you can set up an image map.  The coordinates are relative to the image, not where the image is located in your page.

Comment: ahhhh, okay. i feel idiotic! thanks for the tip

Comment: No worries, now you know.  You have to learn somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't get Dreamweaver to cooperate, you could always try a web app like this:

http://www.image-maps.com/

I've not used it myself, but it looks like you upload an image, the site helps you draw your areas, and you download the code when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

If you find difficult to map the image, instead use `position: relative;` for the container, and later use `<a>` and use following styles

```
a {
   display: block;
   height: 30px; /* Set accordingly */
   width: 30px; /* Set accordingly */
   position: absolute;
   /* Now set top, bottom, left, right according to your requirements */
}
```

Just a side note, use `border: 1px solid #f00;` just to be sure your `<a>` wraps the decided target, which later you can remove or disable the border.

Also you can use `:nth-of-type` for `<a>` so you don't need to declare classes for each `<a>` element